# How to declare a variable with two possible types

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, scope

I have two `Core Data entities` which populate a `UITableView` with 2 sections, one entity for each section. When the user taps on a table row, they are directed to another view where the data of that row is sent. It is currently implemented like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "editValue") {
        let secondViewController = segue.destination as! EditValuesViewController

        if send_array_inc.isEmpty {
            secondViewController.send_array_exp = send_array_exp
        } else if send_array_exp.isEmpty {
            secondViewController.send_array_inc = send_array_inc
        }
    }
}
```

**The Question:**

Since there are two entities, there are two possible types (`Income` and `Expenses`) for the data being sent into the next view. How can I use that data in the next view with one variable? I am doing the below in `ViewDidLoad` but the scope of `send_array` remains within that function. How can I make `send_array` available outside?

```
if send_array_inc.isEmpty {
     var send_array = [Expenses]()
     send_array = send_array_exp
} else if send_array_exp.isEmpty {
     var send_array = [Income]()
     send_array = send_array_inc
}
```

I ideally want to do this **without creating a separate view for each entity** result but I am open to refactor if another solution would be better and realistic. Thank you

Comment: Consider using only one entity and adding a type column to differentiate between expenses and income. Another option to consider is to use inheritance in Core Data and to define the common fields that you want to edit in your view controller in the parent entity.

Comment: I really like that first idea Mike, Thanks man!!

Answer (score 1):

Make your two types of data objects conform to a shared protocol. Make the destination view controller's `send_array` be an object conforming to that protocol.

In your EditValuesViewController's code, interrogate the `send_array` to figure out which type of data object was passed in.

### Edit:

Define a protocol

```
@protocol dataArrayProtocol {
  var dataArray: Array
}
```

Define 2 structs that conform to that protocol

```
struct ExpensesArrayStruct: dataArrayProtocol {
  var dataArray: [Expenses]
}

struct IncomeArrayStruct: dataArrayProtocol {
  var dataArray: [Income]
}
```

give your `EditValuesViewController` a property that conforms to that protocol
    class EditValuesViewController: UIViewController {
       var dataArrayStruct: dataArrayProtocol
    }

And your `prepare(for:sender)` method

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "editValue") {
        let secondViewController = segue.destination as! EditValuesViewController

        if send_array_inc.isEmpty {
            secondViewController.dataArrayStruct = ExpensesArrayStruct(dataArray: send_array_exp)
        } else if send_array_exp.isEmpty {
            secondViewController.dataArrayStruct = IncomeArrayStruct(dataArray: send_array_inc)
        }
    }
}
```

And to handle the data:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  super.viewWillAppear(animated)
  if let expensesStruct = dataArrayStruct as? ExpensesArrayStruct {
     //deal with expenses array
  } else if let incomeStruct = dataArrayStruct as? IncomeArrayStruct {
     //deal with income array
  }
}
```

Note that I banged this code out in the SO editor and have not tried to compile it. I may have made some minor errors. It should give you the idea though.

Comment: It's harder to make generic collections like arrays conform to a shared protocol. You could wrap your array in a struct and make the struct conform to your protocol.